# PHP Is it possible to sum elements of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have an array which has multiple sets of data.

Is it possible to sum elements (not all) of the array.  For example, is it possible to sum the first 5 sets of data in an array, then then next 7, then the next three etc.

EDIT:

I've tried the following but with not joy:

```
for ($p=0; $p<=8; $p++){
    $tot = 0;
    $resp = 0;

    $tot = $tot + $row4['Total_Staff'];
    $resp = $resp + $row4['Total_Resp'];

}
```

Clearly I am not using this correctly!

**Array Output (print_r output):**

```
Array ( [department] => Central>ACME>BusDev [Total_Staff] => 4 [Total_Resp] => 0 ) 
Array ( [department] => Central>ACME>ChemDev [Total_Staff] => 7 [Total_Resp] => 0 ) 
Array ( [department] => Central>ACME>Admin [Total_Staff] => 1 [Total_Resp] => 0 ) 
Array ( [department] => Central>ACME>Chemistry [Total_Staff] => 4 [Total_Resp] => 0 )
```

Comment: sure. with a correctly indexed for cycle.

Comment: Anything is possible. Can you show what you've done so far and ask a specific question for us to help with?

Comment: combination of [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) with [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) should do it.... perhaps you should show why your array makes it any more complicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/array_splice) to remove `$numOfElems` elements from the array and the return them. Use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) to calculate the sum. Repeat the process until the array is empty.

```
$array = array(/* your array */)
$sets = array(5,7,3);
$sum_arr = array();

foreach ($sets as $numOfElems) {
    while (!empty($array)) {
        $elem_arr = array_splice($array, 0, $numOfElems);
        $sum[] = array_sum($elem_arr);
    }
}

print_r($sum_arr);
```

This will repeat the process with the same sets until it reaches the end of array. If you only want `count($sets)` number of iterations, then perhaps, you could change `while` to `if`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/118169)

Comment: Thanks Amal, seem to be having a problem - is this because my array has multiple sets of data (title, staff, responses)?  Output from the above when I implement is lots of `Array ()`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the demo - I think as I have three sets of data per array entry the above isn't working?

Comment: So, for the first three sets of data in the array I need to sum the `staff` part of the array and then `responses' part of the array etc.

Comment: @Homer_J: I have no idea how your array looks like. Add the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($your_array_here, TRUE).'</pre>';` to the question.

Comment: there you go, thanks again for your assistance - struggling to get my head around this.

Comment: @Homer_J: Are you sure you copy-pasted the above statement correctly? I was expecting to see a nicely formatted `print_r()` output. This one's not actually very readable.

Comment: Hi Amal, that is the print_r output!  Exactly as it appears on the page.

Comment: @Homer_J: It looks there are multiple arrays. Are you doing the `print_r()` inside a loop? Please paste the full code somewhere (http://pastie.org for example).